# How do I access individual _id columns when there are multiple _id columns from a join?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Using the typical **_id** column and joining tables and selecting all columns when creating a cursor, will result in a cursor that contains multiple _id columns.

To access a specific **_id** column would then require using the actual offset, as opposed to the column name.

Using hard coded offsets can be problematic, it makes the code harder to read and thus to maintain.

For example two tables **shops** and **aisles** as per

**shops Table has columns**

- **_id**
- **shopname**

**aisles has columns**

- **_id**
- **aisleshoplink**
- **aislename**

Then you might want to get a cursor containing the aisle and the associated shop (aisleshoplink holding the **_id** of the respective shop that the aisle is in).

using `SELECT * FROM aisles LEFT JOIN shops ON aisleshoplink = shops._id`

Will result in Cursor that has columns

- **_id** (aisle's _id offset=0)
- **aisleshoplink** (value will be the respective shop's _id, offset = 1)
- **aislename** (offset =2)
- **_id** (the shop's _id, should match aisleshoplink, offset = 3)
- **shopname** (offset =4)

The resultant Cursor has nothing to distinguish the **_id** columns other than the offset. You can't prefix it with the table name as you could in SQL.

i.e `cursor.getLong(_id)` is ambiguous (appears from limited testing to return the last _id).

`cursor.getLong("aisles._id")` fails with `E/SQLiteCursor: requesting column name with table name -- aisles._id` being issued (results are also inconsistent sometimes only 1 fail will be shown, sometimes all fails will be shown).

**So how should the appropriate _id be retrieved from the cursor, without having to resort to using the offset?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short utilising **AS** to give the duplicate columns names specific column names.

For example instead of

`SELECT * FROM Aisles LEFT JOIN Shops ON aisleshoplink = shops._id`

you could use

`SELECT aisles._id AS aisles_id, aisleshoplink, aislename, shops._id AS shop_id, shopname FROM aisles LEFT JOIN shops ON aisleshoplink = shops._id`

However, you will then not get an **_id** column as may be required (e.g. for  a CursorAdapter). The list of columns may also be quite extensive and you want most. So you could use

`SELECT *, aisles._id AS aisles_id, shops._id AS shops_id FROM aisles LEFT JOIN shops ON aisleshoplink = shops._id`

This has the disadvantage that again there are two **_id** columns, so using the **id** returned, say in an **`OnItemClick`** listener may not be as expected.

So perhaps using the first, with all columns specifically provided including specifically including the appropriate **_id** should be used :-

`SELECT aisle._id, aisles._id AS aisles_id, aisleshoplink, aislename, shops._id AS shop_id, shopname FROM aisles LEFT JOIN shops ON aisleshoplink = shops._id`

To use the above via the SQLite `query` method could be:-

```
String query_tables = "aisles LEFT JOIN shops ON aisleshoplink = shops._id";
String[] columns = {
    "aisle._id".
    "aisles._id AS aisles_id",
    "aisleshoplink",
    "aislename",
    "shops._id AS shop_id",
    "shopname"
    };
Cursor mycursor = db.query(query_tables,
    columns,null,null,null,null,null
);
```

The resultant cursor would have columns :-

- _id
- aisles_id
- aisleshoplink
- aislename
- shops_id
- shopname