# SQLite: Extract _id from joined cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have two tables:

```
A 
_id, name
1  , a

B 
_id, name, a_id
2  , b   , 1
```

How do I retrieve A._id or A.name from a join query, e.g.

```
    public Map<String, String> query() {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON A._id = B.a_id";
        try (Cursor csr = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null)) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            if (csr.moveToNext()) {
                map.put("_id", csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                map.put("name", csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("name")));
            }
            return map;
        }
    }
```

And Helper#query only return [_id = 2, name = b]. Explicitly retrieving the column index by table also does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the cursor column names do not include the table names, so you have a cursor that has two **`_id`** columns.

From limited testing `getColumnIndex` returns the offset of the last column with the same name.

The fix is to ensure that the column names are unique, this can be achievede using **`AS`** e.g. :-

```
public Map<String, String> query() {
    String sql = "SELECT *, A._id AS A_id, B._id AS B_id FROM A JOIN B ON A._id = B.a_id"; //<<<<<< added AS
    try (Cursor csr = getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null)) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        if (csr.moveToNext()) {
            map.put("_id", csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("A_id"))); //<<<< use column alias
            map.put("name", csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("name")));
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

This then allows you to do away with the more problematic/less flexible hard coded column offsets.

A more comprehensive answer is [here - How do I access individual _id columns when there are multiple _id columns from a join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46165869/how-do-i-access-individual-id-columns-when-there-are-multiple-id-columns-from)

Comment: Thank you, I also think the best option so far is to include the table name in every single column to avoid collision.