# SQLite 1:M relationship

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

As part of project i am making android app that tracks users workouts in the gym. With the workouts and exercises with various set, weight and reps. This will a 1:M relationship with the workout id being the foreign key. I am still new to android and sqlite so i just wanted to check that code below is correct before going ahead.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

DBHelper

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static String DATABASE_NAME = "gym_db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TABLE_WORKOUT = "workout_table";
public static final String WORKOUT_ID = "_id";
public static final String WORKOUT_NAME = "workout_name";

public static final String TABLE_EXERCISE = "exercise_table";
public static final String EXERCISE_ID = "exercise_id";
public static final String EXERCISE_NAME = "exercise_name";
public static final String EXERCISE_SET = "exercise_set";
public static final String EXERCISE_WEIGHT = "exercise_weight";
public static final String EXERCISE_REP = "exercise_rep";

public static final String createWorkoutTable = "CREATE TABLE" + TABLE_WORKOUT + "("
        +WORKOUT_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + WORKOUT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"+
        ");";


public static final String createExerciseTable = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EXERCISE + "("
        +EXERCISE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + EXERCISE_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + EXERCISE_SET + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + EXERCISE_WEIGHT + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + EXERCISE_REP + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + WORKOUT_ID + "FOREIGN KEY"+
        "(;";
```

I have also turned on the foreign key in the onUpgrade method

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    super.onOpen(db);
    if (!db.isReadOnly()){
        db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
    }
```

Comment: Is there a specific error you need help with?

Comment: no i was just checking that i have used the correct syntax to create the tables

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is **not** a code review site.

Comment: Ok any ideas on a query where I can select the workouts with the joined exercises ?

Comment: I would advice you to read through the Help Center first so you can get a general idea about what this site is for first: https://stackoverflow.com/help Especially this part is quite relevant for you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

1. Coding `WORKOUT_ID + "FOREIGN KEY"` will not have the desired (assuming this is to be a foreign key constraint) result.

In theory (see later) the above would create a column named **_id** with a column type of FOREIGN KEY (which would be translated/converted to a column type of **NUMERIC**). However, as `FOREIGN` is a keyword the attempt to set the column type would fail with a syntax error. You need to specify a column type which would likely be `INTEGER`. So you would have `WORKOUT_ID` + " INTEGER ....".

However `FOREIGN KEY` on it's own is insufficient and also in the wrong place.
There are two ways of defining a `FOREIGN KEY`, as part of the column definition or as part of the table definition.

The former, (column definition) does not use the `FOREIGN KEY` keyword but the missing 2nd part the `REFERENCES` (i.e. saying what the primary table is along with the referenced column) using this method you would use :-

```
WORKOUT_ID + " INTEGER REFERENCES " + TABLE_WORKOUT +"(" + WORKOUT_ID +")"
```

The latter (table definition) does use the FOREIGN KEY keyword. You would code this along the lines of :-

```
WORKOUT_ID + " INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY (" + WORKOUT_ ID + ") REFERENCES " + TABLE_WORKOUT + "(" + WORKOUT_ID + ")"
```

- You may wish to have a look at [SQLite Foreign Key Support](https://sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

---

2. The following line `"(;"` will result in a syntax error it should be `");"`.

I'd also suggest that using **`_id`** as the name of the column that references the **`_id`** column may cause confusion and difficulties (e.g. when you do a select with a join you'd have two **`_id`** columns in the resultant Cursor).

I'd suggest using a different column name e.g **workout_id_reference**.

- This goes into some detail of this scenario [How do I access individual _id columns when there are multiple _id columns from a join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46165869/how-do-i-access-individual-id-columns-when-there-are-multiple-id-columns-from)